# Java Regex: how to use OR operation to extract substring

Tags: java, regex, string

Now I am having a set of strings in the following two formats (mixed together):

```
1. /c/en/SUBSTRING
2. /c/en/SUBSTRING/some_other_string
```

And I want to use the single Java Regex to extract the SUBSTRING from the strings. I know how to do it for the the second case: `Pattern.compile("^/c/en/(\\w+)/")`. Obviously I can use two Regex, one for the first case and one for the second case, and then take the result of the successful one. But that is a waste of computation. How can I take the first case into consideration and use a single Regex to finish the task?

I tried `"^/c/en/(\\w+)[/|$]"` and `"^/c/en/(\\w+)/|$"` but they do not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
Pattern.compile("^/c/en/([^/]+)")
```

and use a `Matcher`'s `.find()` against the input. The substring will be available in this matcher's `.group(1)`.

Comment: That works, thanks. What is the function of "[" and "]" in Java Regex?

Comment: `[...]` is a character class, it matches one character in the class. Here I use `[^...]`, which is a _complemented_ character class. It matches one character _not_ in the class. So, `[^/]` essentially matches one character which is not a `/`.